# Locally 401 Working, Staging Server getting a 302 instead

Tags: grails, jquery, spring-security, mod-proxy

I'm probably not going to get all the required info needed to help the first stab but I'll do the best I can and edit this as we go along.

I've got a Grails 1.3.7 application using Spring-Security-Core plugin.  I'm working on code that deals with session timeouts and ajax requests.  In the LoginController, I have the following:

```
def authAjax = {
    session.SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY = null
    response.sendError HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED
}
```

In a global JavaScript file, I have the following:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
     error: function(xhr, status, err) {
       if (xhr.status == 401) {
         $('#login-dialog').dialog({ // show ajax login });
       }
     }
});
```

When I run this locally everything works as expected. When my session timesout, I see a 401 in FireBug console and I get the Login dialog.  When I deploy this to our staging server, I'm only getting the 302 and never getting into authAjax therefor never getting the 401.

The main difference between local dev and staging is that I'm using mod_proxy with apache httpd to proxy the requests back and forth to Tomcat.  My assumption is this is why I'm getting a 302 and not the 401 but I'm not 100% sure.

My question(s)

1. Is the mod_proxy causing the 302
2. How can I resolve this so that it works like it does locally, but still using mod_proxy.

**UPDATE:**

Per the recent comments, locally, when I get the 401 I am seeing this:

```
POST https://localhost:8080/admin/bookProject/edit 302 Moved Temporarily
GET http://localhost:8080/login/authAjax 401 Unauthorized
```

And I am seeing debug from the authAjax method

On the staging server I am getting:

```
POST https://server.com/admin/bookProject/edit 302 Moved Temporarily
```

And I am *not* seeing any debug from authAjax, so I'm not even getting there.

Comment: Help us out a bit more, please - can you let us know what URL you are being 302 (redirected) to? You may be getting redirected (for example) to a server-side login page.

Comment: try adding some log.debug in def authAjax just to see if is even getting there in your staging server!

Comment: Hi, what version of the SpringSecurity plugin are you using?  my authAjax looks like this (Excuse the wonky formatting!):                                       def authAjax = {
  println "in AuthAjax"
  response.setHeader 'Location', SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.auth.ajaxLoginFormUrl
  response.sendError HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED
 } You could try explicitly setting the header to redirect to?

Comment: Ok, thats the same as me - Could you try adding:                   `Response.setHeader 'Location', SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.auth.ajaxLoginFormUrl`before the response.sendError line in authAjax? I have that line but I didn't record why I put it in, although I was having the same problems as you!

Comment: I tried that yesterday after your comment and it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Code for your Ajax call:

```
statusCode: {
    401: function(){
        // redirect code to login page
    }
}
```