# Grails isn't responding with a 401 during ajax request and timed out session

Tags: angularjs, grails, spring-security

I'm using grails along with spring security and angularjs. When a user session has expired and the user clicks an ajax action on the page, rather than respond with a 401, the application attempts to redirect to the login page which no response from the original ajax action.

I'm still using a traditional login page and some my application still has some traditional page links, so when a session has expired and a user clicks a page link, I would like to redirect to the login page.

If a user clicks on an ajax request, I would like to get a 401 response rather than the redirected html response so that I can do a redirect in my javascript.

I have the following config setting.

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.providerNames = ['hriLoginClientAuthenticationProvider']
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.failureHandler.defaultFailureUrl = '/login?error=1'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = '/login'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
```

What do I need to do to get ajax request to not redirect to the login page?

Comment: Simple and more clear answer for your query [https://stackoverflow.com/a/47757842/4282369](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47757842/4282369)

Answer (score 1):

I've run into a similar issue and have implemented a filter in the filter chain to detect AJAX requests and respond with a customized HTTP status (you can change it to 401 if you like).

Basically there are three parts to this. The first, is the filter. It's a servlet filter and examines the request as well as the state of the authentication in the session. Second, defining the filter as a bean within the application context in `Resources.groovy`. Finally, inserting it into the Spring Security filter chain, which I've done in `Bootstrap.groovy`.

I'll walk you through this now.

First the servlet filter (under src/java)

```
package com.xyz.security;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolver;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.ThrowableAnalyzer;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.ThrowableCauseExtractor;
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean;

public class AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    // private static final Logger logger =
    // LoggerFactory.getLogger(AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter.class);

    private ThrowableAnalyzer throwableAnalyzer = new DefaultThrowableAnalyzer();
    private AuthenticationTrustResolver authenticationTrustResolver = new AuthenticationTrustResolverImpl();

    private int customSessionExpiredErrorCode = 901;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
            FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        try {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);

            // logger.debug("Chain processed normally");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Throwable[] causeChain = throwableAnalyzer.determineCauseChain(ex);
            RuntimeException ase = (AuthenticationException) throwableAnalyzer
                    .getFirstThrowableOfType(AuthenticationException.class,
                            causeChain);

            if (ase == null) {
                ase = (AccessDeniedException) throwableAnalyzer
                        .getFirstThrowableOfType(AccessDeniedException.class,
                                causeChain);
            }

            if (ase != null) {
                if (ase instanceof AuthenticationException) {
                    throw ase;
                } else if (ase instanceof AccessDeniedException) {

                    if (authenticationTrustResolver
                            .isAnonymous(SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                                    .getAuthentication())) {
                        // logger.info("User session expired or not logged in yet");
                        String ajaxHeader = ((HttpServletRequest) request)
                                .getHeader("X-Requested-With");

                        if ("XMLHttpRequest".equals(ajaxHeader)) {
                            // logger.info("Ajax call detected, send {} error code",
                            // this.customSessionExpiredErrorCode);
                            HttpServletResponse resp = (HttpServletResponse) response;
                            resp.sendError(this.customSessionExpiredErrorCode);
                        } else {
                            // logger.info("Redirect to login page");
                            throw ase;
                        }
                    } else {
                        throw ase;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

    private static final class DefaultThrowableAnalyzer extends
            ThrowableAnalyzer {
        /**
         * @see org.springframework.security.web.util.ThrowableAnalyzer#initExtractorMap()
         */
        protected void initExtractorMap() {
            super.initExtractorMap();

            registerExtractor(ServletException.class,
                    new ThrowableCauseExtractor() {
                        public Throwable extractCause(Throwable throwable) {
                            ThrowableAnalyzer.verifyThrowableHierarchy(
                                    throwable, ServletException.class);
                            return ((ServletException) throwable)
                                    .getRootCause();
                        }
                    });
        }

    }

    public void setCustomSessionExpiredErrorCode(
            int customSessionExpiredErrorCode) {
        this.customSessionExpiredErrorCode = customSessionExpiredErrorCode;
    }
}
```

Second, defining the filter as a bean in the application context in `Resources.groovy`

```
beans = {
    ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter(com.xyz.security.AjaxTimeoutRedirectFilter)
}
```

And finally, getting the filter into the Spring Security filter chain (I used `BootStrap.groovy` for this)

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SecurityFilterPosition
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityUtils
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

        SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter('ajaxTimeoutRedirectFilter', SecurityFilterPosition.EXCEPTION_TRANSLATION_FILTER.order + 10)

    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider "locking a screen" when the user is idle on a client-side? Of course you should handle end of a session on server-side but in fact it seems even cleaner and more secure solution than waiting for an action from client side (especially if user has left and left on a screen some sensitive data).

Check out this [ng-idle](https://github.com/hackedbychinese/ng-idle) directive.