# What is the best way to check if the user is logged in or not in grails Spring Security?

Tags: grails, spring-security, interceptor, grails-plugin, grails-3.1

I would like to check if the user is logged in or not.I have integrated interceptor in most of the projects to check if user is logged in . But this does-not work well with AJAX request and matching all the controllers in the interceptor causes filter to be applied for all controllers including /static/** ,where in this case i will have to exclude (.excludes(uri: "/static/**")) .Is this the correct and standard way of doing?

```
LoginInterceptor() {
        matchAll()
                .excludes(controller: "login") 
                .excludes(controller: "signUp") 
                .excludes(uri: "/static/**")
                .excludes(uri: "/assets/**")
    }
    boolean before() {
        if (!springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()) {
            flash.message="You need to login to access furthur pages"
            redirect( controller: 'login',action: 'auth');
            return false
        }
        true
    }

    boolean after() { true }

    void afterView() {
        // no-op
    }
```

The above code doesnot work with the AJAX request . How do i make a generic interceptor which works well with both AJAX and WEB request? And is this a standard way of monitoring request for logged in?

Comment: what do you mean by `does-not work well` .. are you getting error or unexpected result. can you say what is the exact problem?

Comment: @devbd First thing is ,the ajax requests for JSON so how will my interceptor redirect to the auth page. Second When i apply interceptor for matchAll(), it will filter /static/** as well and i think this is not a proper solution for checking if the user is logged or not.

Comment: you have to handle `redirect` along with Ajax request in your JS code . Then check if you have any URL that matches exactly `/static/**` .. i dont think you have a url exactly like  `/static/**`.

Comment: /static/** is the  url for /src/main/webapp/ in grails 3+

Comment: `/static/**` is a `pattern` not a direct url.

Comment: See my answer to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853996/grails-isnt-responding-with-a-401-during-ajax-request-and-timed-out-session/35854255#35854255) it may point you in the right direction.

Comment: "/static/** is the url for /src/main/webapp/ in grails 3+" - Is that true by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use spring security plugin. You can do it by configuring security config. You can find more [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/latest/#requestMappings)

For ajax request you can check return code and if it is == 403, you can redirect user to the login page.

Comment: For ajax request : 403 if for page without permission. My ajax request to ---->  POSTXHR
http://localhost:8080/home/index2 get me ------->
[HTTP/1.1 302 Found 4ms]
GETXHR
http://localhost:8080/login/authAjax

Comment: @ujjwolshrestha so it's redirect you to the login/authAjax, am I right? you can look on 'adh.ajaxErrorPage' property in docs. maybe it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

When working on my project, I found the following way to check the log-in status.

```
def springSecurityService

boolean canEdit() {
   boolean isLoggedIn = springSecurityService.isLoggedIn()
   if (!isLoggedIn) { return false }
      boolean hasAdminOrCuratorRole = userService.isLoggedInUserACurator() || userService.isLoggedInUserAAdmin()
   hasAdminOrCuratorRole
}
```

Hope this helps!